# laravel select2 on submit receive blank page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

have an issue. When submitting a form with select2 receive a completely blank page. don't understand why controller doesn't work. just need send store id.

```
<form  id='filter' action="{{ route("admin.product.filter") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @method('get')
        <select name="store" id="store" class="form-control store">
            <option value="0">All</option>
            @foreach($stores as $store)
                <option value="{{$store->id}}">{{$store->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <div>
           <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
        </div>
</form>
```

via select2

```
$('.store').select2({
    templateResult: formatState
});

    function formatState (state) {
    if (!state.id) {
        return state.text;
    }
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost/gadmin/public/shops ";
    var $state = $(
        '<span><img src="' + baseUrl + '/' + state.element.value + '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' + state.text + '</span>'
    );
    return $state;
};
$('#filter').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    $('#filter').submit();
});
```

My controller

```
    public function filter(Request $request)
    {

        $item=Product::with('translation:name,product_id')->get();
        $stores=Store::select('id','name')->get();

        return view('admin.product.index', compact('item','stores'));
    }
```

and my route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('product/filter','Admin\ProductController@filter')->name('product.filter');

});
```

Comment: Are you sure `admin.product.index` has contents?

Comment: @HazemMohamed yeah this is copy of my index function and index function load right

Comment: ```public function index()
    {

     $item=Product::with('translation:name,product_id')->get();
     $stores=Store::select('id','name')->get();


        return view('admin.product.index', compact('item','stores'));
        //  
    }```    --- work well

Comment: do you see any errors in developer tools console?

Comment: @HazemMohamed no just full blank page, tried to clear all cache, and it doesn't resolved

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for this, especially that I still don't have a concrete solution but at least I could manage to find the problem causing this behavior.

If you remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part from your HTML template, the blank page error will be resolved.

Of course, now I need to find a way to use the multipart form ecoding type without somehow breaking PHP...